# iterating over a directory in python's behave

Tags: python, gherkin, python-behave

I'm using python's behave BDD tool, and I have a directory of xml config files that I'd like to run some automatic tests against before running other end to end tests.  I've started writing some feature files using scenario outlines, and just listing all the file names in the outline, but that doesn't scale well as new files are added.

Alternatively, I was looking at reading all the filenames in the directory and putting them as a list in the context variable using the "before_scenario" function in environment.py.  The problem I see with that is then you are testing all of the files at once, instead of checking each file as its own scenario with its own set of steps, which isn't the intent of the tool.

I guess what I'd like to do is something like a scenario outline, but without generating a static table.  There are dozens of files, so if I don't have to statically define everything, that would be best.  I'm not sure that's really supported, but maybe someone else has solved this.

```
# Created by max at 8/2/18
Feature: XML syntax validation
  # Enter feature description here
  @XML
  Scenario Outline: A config file should validate against canary.xsd
  Given we have the <CanaryConfig> config file
  When we validate against canary.xsd
  Then it should validate correctly

  Examples: Config Files
    | CanaryConfig |
    | ACM.xml |
    | sim-tacbio2.xml |

  @XML
  Scenario Outline: A sensor definition file should validate
  Given we have a <sensor definition> sensor definition
  When we validate against a CCSI schema
  Then it should validate correctly

  Examples:
    | sensor definition |
    | ACM.xml  |
    | tacbio2.xml |
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but...

Have you considered going outside of the Behave framework for a solution to this? For instance, if you're running Behave via a [main method](https://github.com/behave/behave/blob/master/tasks/__main__.py) *which merely calls Behave*, then you could do this pre-check beforehand using just plain old Python.

One method to go about doing so would be to use Python's built-in `os.listdir()` function. Initially, you could save a text file with the names of the existing XML config files and write these to your `.feature` file using Python. You could then subsequently check if new files have been added to the directory by comparing the current directory's files to the ones listed in the text file. In the case that they already exist, then no changes are needed and your program can be run; in the case that they don't exist, then you could once again use Python to write these config files to your `.feature` file.

This would be a dynamic approach, in that you wouldn't have to statically define anything, but that the names of the config files *would* be stored in a text file.